# Qbs: Can Module install files?

Tags: qbs

I want to have a module which will export all needed dependencies like include path, library path and will install needed runtime libraries.

```
Module {
    Depends { name: "cpp" }
    property path libLocation: ""
    cpp.dynamicLibraries: [
        "mylib"
    ]
    cpp.staticLibraries: [
        "mylib"
    ]
    cpp.includePaths: [
        libLocation + "include/",
    ]
    cpp.libraryPaths: [
        libLocation + "lib/",
    ]
    Group {
        name: "runtime libraries"
        qbs.install: true
        prefix: 'lib_location/'
        files: ["*.dll"]
    }
}
```

Everything works, but files are not installed. Is it possible to do that?

*Update 1*:

Files **are** correctly installed:

- if full or relative paths are specified directly(as literals)
- by using Project's properties.

Working solution:

```
Module {
    ...
    Group {
        name: "runtime libraries"
        prefix: "D:/Projects/MyProject/Dependencies/SDL2pp/mingw/bin/" // works!
        //prefix: project.dependenciesPath + "SDL2pp/mingw/bin/" // also works!

        files: "*.dll"
        qbs.install: true
    }
}
```

But when I'm trying to use Module's property it says: "Reference Error: Can't find variable: ..."

```
Module {
    ...
    property bool installDlls: true
    property string libPath:  ""
    Group {
        name: "runtime libraries"
        prefix: libPath // Can't find variable
        files: "*.dll"
        qbs.install: installDlls // Can't find variable
    }
}
```

Also, It is not work if FileInfo module is used for building a path. Outside the Group path was corectly resolved.

```
import qbs
import qbs.FileInfo

Module {
    ...
    Group {
        name: "runtime libraries"
        prefix: FileInfo.joinPaths(project.dependenciesPaths, './SDL2pp/mingw/bin/') // silently not works
        files: "*.dll"
        qbs.install: true
    }
}
```

*Conclusion*
I've found 2 solutuins of it:

- hadrcoded path as a literal. Unportable solution
- using Project's property. Portable, but depends on Project item.

I don't know why Module's properties can't be used inside a Group. Are there some limitations or it's a bug?

Comment: We've changed the location which Group paths are relative to, when located in modules. What version of Qbs are you using and are you sure "lib_location/" is being resolved to the correct absolute path?

Comment: @JakePetroules Qbs version: 1.7.1. I was wrong by saying that it's not installed at all. I've updated my question with details about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Late but found this post trying to do the same, maybe it helps other people.
Found out that using a Module's property inside a Group can be done by giving the Module an id and referencing the property using the id like this

`Module {
    id: mymodule
    ...
    property bool installDlls: true
    property string libPath:  ""
    Group {
        name: "runtime libraries"
        prefix: mymodule.libPath
        files: "*.dll"
        qbs.install: mymodule.installDlls
    }
}`

I'm using Qbs 1.12.1